$(C): (x-4)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4, A(-1;0), B(-3;0), M \in (C).$ How to find min/max of $P = MA + MB?$
$(C): (x-4)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4$
$A(-1;0)$
$B(-3;0)$
$K(-2;0)$
$M$ is a point on the circle.
I wonder what the method is to find the minimum value of $MA + MB$ as $M$ is moving on $(C)$. I'd love to hear both algebraic and geometric approaches, should they be available.
Thank you!


Shouldn't the point M be on line joining the Center of circle $(4,3)$ and $A\equiv (-1,0)$. $MB$ will be minimum when $MA$ will be minimum and $MB$ will be maximum when $MA$ will be maximum

@Maverick Hi, it appears that's not true. MB is minimum when M is the intersection of $BI$ and $(C),$ while MA is minimum when M is the intersection of $AI$ and $(C),$ so they do not appear to achieve minimum values at the same time.
